# How to create 2x2 matrix to rotate vector to right side?

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, rotations

I have vector `u=(x,y)` and i need to create matrix M: `M*u=(1,0)`.

But that matrix has to rotate vector, instead of keep and scale the x unit. So when i apply it on different vectors, the angle between them won't change.

*Btw, this **isn't** homework! We haven't learned any matrices at school yet. ;)*

Comment: But, when you talk of rotating, is (x,y) on the unit circle? If so, if you can find out the angle of the vector 0u , i.e., the number 'r' of radians at (x,y) , starting at (1,0), all you need to do is to rotate (x,y) by '-r', and this is just given by a matrix with $a_ii=cost$; $a_1i=sint$ and $a_{21}=-sint$. Maybe the simplest example is that of using a matrix with all entries $\frac {2^{0.5}}{2}$ , except for $a_{21}= -\frac {2^{0.5}}{2}$

Comment: It might be quite helpful if you show us a picture of what you want to happen...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to find the transformation between the $x,y$
coordinates of a point and the $x^{\prime },y^{\prime }$ coordinates of the
same point in a rotated system of coordinates, followed by a multiplication
by the factor $k=1/\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$, so that $x^{\prime \prime
}=kx^{\prime }=1$ and $y^{\prime \prime }=kx^{\prime }=0$. The rotation
angle should be $\theta =\arctan \frac{y}{x}$.

[image]

From trigonometry, we know that

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x^{\prime }=x\cos \theta +y\sin \theta =\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}} \\ 
y^{\prime }=-x\sin \theta +y\cos \theta =0
\end{array}
\right. 
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
and since

$$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos \left( \arctan \frac{y}{x}\right)  &=&\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}} \\
\sin \left( \arctan \frac{y}{x}\right)  &=&\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}, \\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

we have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x^{\prime \prime }=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}x^{\prime }=\frac{x^{2}}{
x^{2}+y^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=1 \\ 
y^{\prime \prime }=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}y^{\prime }=-\frac{xy}{
x^{2}+y^{2}}+\frac{xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=0.
\end{array}
\right. 
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

> We haven't learned any matrices at school yet.

In [matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29) notation$^1$

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{pmatrix}
x^{\prime \prime } \\ 
y^{\prime \prime }
\end{pmatrix}
&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}
\begin{pmatrix}
x^{\prime } \\ 
y^{\prime }
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & \frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \\ 
-\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & \frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

So
$$
M=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & \frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \\ 
-\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & \frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

--

$^1$ Product of a $2\times 2$ matrix by a $2\times 1$ matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\ 
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{1} \\ 
b_{2}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}b_{1}+a_{12}b_{2} \\ 
a_{21}b_{1}+a_{22}b_{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and product between a scalar $\alpha$ and a $2\times 1$ matrix

$$\alpha 
\begin{pmatrix}
c_{1} \\ 
c_{2}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha c_{1} \\ 
\alpha c_{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want a 2$\times$2 [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) that sends $\vec{u}=(x,y)$ to $\vec{e}_1=(1,0)$. (The question is a bit unclear in my opinion: what does it mean to "keep and scale the x unit"? Isn't that an oxy-moron? I assume you want to preserve angles under transformation, i.e. $\angle\vec{a}\vec{b}=\angle(M\vec{a})(M\vec{b})$, right?) The [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)'s angle formula gives $\cos\theta=\vec{u}\cdot\vec{e_1}/r$, where $\theta$ is the angle from $\vec{e}_1$ to $\vec{u}$ and $r=\|\vec{u}\|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the magnitude. Now we use this to find the entries of the rotation matrix $R(-\theta)$ (the matrix transforms counterclockwise normally, so to get it to go backwards we need to negate the angle sign); see the Wikipedia link. Note $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$. Moreover, we have to divide this rotation matrix by another $r$ so that it scales down $\vec{u}$ to unit size. Thus we have

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}x/r^2&y/r^2\\-y/r^2&x/r^2\end{pmatrix}.$$

You can check that this indeed sends $\vec{u}$ to $\vec{e}_1$.

Comment: $(x/r)x+(y/r)y=(x^2+y^2)/r=r^2/r=r$ instead of $1$. In your notation I have computed $$M=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{x}{r^2} & \frac{y}{r^{2}} \\ 
-\frac{y}{r^{2}} & \frac{x}{r^{2}}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: @Americo: Thanks for the catch. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

M =

```
[ x y
  -y x ]
/ (x^2 + y^2) ^(1/2)
```

Comment: The question was how to create it...