# Matrices that Commute with of a Specific matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers. Considere the $2\times 2$ matrix 
\begin{equation*}A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\-b&a\end{array}\right].
\end{equation*}
What is the centralizer of the matrix $A$ in $M_2(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: Have you tried working it out from the definition?

Answer (score 4):

If $b=0$, then $A=aI_2$ and we have $AX=XA$ for every $X \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. the centralizer of $A=aI_2$ is the whole $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Let us now assume that $b\ne 0$, and let
$$
X=\left[\begin{array}{cc}x_{11}&x_{12}\\x_{21}&x_{21}\end{array}\right] \in M_2(\mathbb{R}).
$$
Then 
\begin{eqnarray}
AX&=&\left[\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\-b&a\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}x_{11}&x_{12}\\x_{21}&x_{22}\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}ax_{11}+bx_{21}&ax_{12}+bx_{22}\\-bx_{11}+ax_{21}&-bx_{12}+ax_{22}\end{array}\right]\cr
XA&=&\left[\begin{array}{cc}x_{11}&x_{12}\\x_{21}&x_{22}\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\-b&a\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}ax_{11}-bx_{12}&bx_{11}+ax_{12}\\ax_{21}-bx_{22}&bx_{21}+ax_{22}\end{array}\right]\cr
\end{eqnarray}
It follows that
$$
AX=XA \iff 
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
ax_{11}+bx_{21}=ax_{11}-bx_{12}\\
ax_{12}+bx_{22}=bx_{11}+ax_{12}\\
-bx_{11}+ax_{21}=ax_{21}-bx_{22}\\
-bx_{12}+ax_{22}=bx_{21}+ax_{22}
\end{array}
\right.\iff
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
b(x_{11}-x_{22})=0\\
b(x_{12}+x_{21})=0
\end{array}
\right..
$$
Since $b\ne 0$, we have $x_{22}=x_{11},\ x_{21}=-x_{12}$, i.e. the centralizer of $A$ is formed by matrices of the form
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
x&y\\
-y&x
\end{array}
\right], \quad x, y \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: It deserves mention that the set of matrices of this shape is _isomorphic to $\mathbb C$_, with matrix addition and multiplication corresponding to addition and multiplication of complex numbers. (In fact I've seen this used as a _definition_ of the complex numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Just solve the matrix equation:

$$\begin{pmatrix}x&y\\z&w\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\\!\!\!-b&a\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\\!\!\!-b&a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x&y\\z&w\end{pmatrix}$$

For example, entries $\,1-1\,,\,2-2\,$ give us

$$ax-by=ax+bz\,\,,\,\,bz+aw=-by+aw$$

and from here, for example, we obtain

$$-by=bz\Longrightarrow b=0\,\,\,or\,\,\,-y=z\,\,,\,etc.$$

Comment: Where did you get the $=a$ part of your equation?  Also, isn't $ax+by=ax+bz$ an $bz+aw=-by+aw$, not all equal?

Comment: Yup. That, with that weird $\,=a\,$ , was part of a prior line that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, if two matrices commute <del>they must have the same eigenvectors</del> [if they are simultaneously diagonlizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56307/simultaneous-diagonalization).  Let $Av = \lambda v$  and $AB = BA$.  Then

$$  A(Bv)= (BA)(v) =    \lambda (Bv)     $$

Simultaneously diagonzliable matrices are discussed a few times in math.stackexchange:

- [Matrices commute if and only if they share a common basis of eigenvectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6258/matrices-commute-common-set-of-eigenvectors)
- [How do I prove that in every commuting family there is a common eigenvector?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197331/how-do-i-prove-that-in-every-commuting-family-there-is-a-common-eigenvector)

In any case, since $\det A = a^2 + b^2 \neq 0$ your matrix is a [rotation in the plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63503/how-to-create-2x2-matrix-to-rotate-vector-to-right-side).  Therefore $B$ must also be a rotation, so

$$ B  = c \left( \begin{array}{cc}  \cos \theta  &  -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta  & \cos \theta  \end{array} \right) 
= \left( \begin{array}{cc}  c  &  -d \\ d  & c  \end{array} \right)$$
for some $c, d \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: A rotation should not have $c=1$?